# POSTing json data and file to Ruby on Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman

I'm very new to ruby on rails, so its likely that I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure this out for the life of me.

I have created an API server with ruby on rails, and I can't seem to be able to post JSON along with a picture. I keep receiving an error on the server side, complaining about the encoding being wrong.

```
ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: invalid %-encoding 
.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/uri/common.rb:324:in decode_www_form_component'
```

I am using Postman to make the request. I am using the `form-data` option to include a text entry with my JSON, and a file entry with my PNG. The header Content-Type is multipart/mixed. And the individual key/value pairs are `application/json` and `image/png` respectively. I can't tell if this is a postman issue, a ruby controller issue. or a bug.

[image: Postman request image]

[image: Post def]

[image: Required fields]

Any insight or further questions will help me.

EDIT:
Here is the code from my post request from inside postman.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/events/1/eventphotos/' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed' \
--form 'data={
    "eventphoto":{
        "event_id":1,
        "photopath":"nothing to see here"
    }
}' \
--form 'picture=@/Users/chancefinley/Downloads/mushroom.png'
```

Comment: In Postman you have a Code option (underneath the Send button), can you paste what's in there?

Comment: @Joel_Blum didn't even know that that existed. I have edited the question and added it above

Comment: Something im noticing that in the generated curl code, postman is not including the subtypes to my form data that im submitting. Perhaps thats what is tripping my rails app?

Comment: Send the data as `x-www-form-urlencoded` in PostMan and the error will be gone. It happens when you encounter an invalid character relative to the current encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem ended up being that I needed a view which would contain a form. You know, so that the formdata request has something to actually submit to...... Dumb mistake. Learned my lesson

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the case, but have you added active storage to your project?
because if not, I think it's having trouble inserting the file into the database,
you could transform the image into base 64 encoding and save it as a string or follow this guide and see if it helps: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/rails-image-upload-101-f9bf245e389b

Comment: i considered that. i am currently using the CarrierWave gem.

Comment: @Pants  But is the problem in your real Rails app (carrierwave gem) or in Postman?

Comment: @Joel_Blum thats my dilemma. Don't know enough about either to know which is right yet.